# Display current logged-in user

Tags: php, symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I'm using Symfony and sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

How do I display, in a template, the username of the current user ?

I've tried **$this->getUser()->getUsername()**, but all I get is the error : "Call to undefined method sfPHPView::getUser."

I'm trying to display the username in a layout.php, not in a particular module/template

Comment: Well according to your error, $this does not have a function called getUser(), make sure you are calling it from the right object.

Comment: you can find answers on that kind of questions in the documentation on the Symfony-project website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In a template (view)**, use `$sf_user`:

For the username:

```
echo $sf_user->getUsername();
```

For the id:

```
echo $sf_user->getAttribute('user_id', null, 'sfGuardSecurityUser');
```

Or, **in an action (controller)**, you can do what you're doing in your question:

```
$this->username = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
```

and then `$username` will be available in your view template.

See [template shortcuts](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_template_shortcuts) in the Symfony docs for other view variable shortcuts.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it's better to not use $sf_user in a template, you can better retrieve all the needed data in an action and then use a variable filled with the data to be used in the template. Just to seperate business and views.

Comment: I think it depends how much logic you're going to do in the view - if you're simply displaying the username, then I don't see any harm in it - it's a variable you're echoing out, no additional logic required (same as `echo $myObj->field;` really).  If you need to do manipulation on that variable prior to display, then it's better to keep it in the action yes.

Comment: It causes an error when no user is logged in though ... any ideas ? I tried isset ans is_object, but they seem to always return true.

Comment: It's because getUsername() really calls getGuardUser()->getUsername(). As you're not logged in GuardUser is not there. Make a check first with $sf_user->isAuthenticated().

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. One of them may work.

```
$this->getSfGuardUser()
$this->getGuardUser()
$this->getUser()->getSfGuardUser()
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()
```